# Is a saved and loaded data.table with qs a correct data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am saving a data.table as a qs file when I am loading the data.table again it doesn't seem to behave immediately like a data.table.

To clarify what I mean with that. Here is an example:

```
library(data.table)
library(qs)

n <- 10000
dt <- data.table(x = rnorm(n), y = rnorm(n))

cnames <- colnames(dt)
dt[, new_col_1 := 1]
cnames
[1] "x"         "y"         "new_col_1"

cnames <- colnames(dt)
dt[, new_col_2 := 1]
cnames
[1] "x"         "y"         "new_col_1" "new_col_2"
```

So the function `colnames()` is a pointer to the column names of the data.table `dt`.
But if I do the same with a saved and loaded data.table this happens

```
n <- 10000
dt <- data.table(x = rnorm(n), y = rnorm(n))
qs::qsave(dt, "dt_saved.qs")

dt_saved <- qs::qread("dt_saved.qs")
cnames <- colnames(dt_saved)
dt_saved[, new_col_1 := 1]
cnames
[1] "x" "y"

cnames <- colnames(dt_saved)
dt_saved[, new_col_2 := 1]
cnames
[1] "x"         "y"         "new_col_1" "new_col_2"
```

So only after the data.table is modified the function `colnames()` is a pointer.

Some extra information:

```
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
qs_0.25.1
data.table_1.14.2
```

Comment: Sure it has the data.table class still otherwise it would not to allow the `:=` so I think it has to do with the internal.selfref which is not present/valid after loading your data. So you assign the colnames to cnames, but there is no reference yet to update it to. When you assign a new column, the internal.selfref is set, so it knows next new column in colnames from that point on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your data.table in the stored file has no (or no valid) internal pointer, so it cannot update by reference (as there is no reference).

You can demonstrate it with a dput as well.

```
# create a data.table, but it has no internal.selfref
dt <- structure(list(x = c("A", "B", "C"), y = 1:3), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

cnames <- colnames(dt)
dt[, new_col_1 := 1]

# Warning message:
# In `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(new_col_1, 1)) :
#   Invalid .internal.selfref detected and fixed by taking a (shallow) copy of the data.table so that := can add this new column by reference. At an earlier point, this data.table has been copied by R (or was created manually using structure() or similar). Avoid names<- and attr<- which in R currently (and oddly) may copy the whole data.table. Use set* syntax instead to avoid copying: ?set, ?setnames and ?setattr. If this message doesn't help, please report your use case to the data.table issue tracker so the root cause can be fixed or this message improved.

cnames

# [1] "x" "y"
```

So you can see that the reference is created from the point you assign the new column, but it cannot update cnames as there is not a reference there.

You can use setDT right after loading your data so you get the reference also on cnames

```
dt <- structure(list(x = c("A", "B", "C"), y = 1:3), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

setDT(dt) # create reference so cnames updates on reference as well

cnames <- colnames(dt)
dt[, new_col_1 := 1]
cnames
# [1] "x"         "y"         "new_col_1"
```